# flask swagger is executing but not showing results in browser

Tags: python, flask, swagger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLmFt.png)I have a flask app and im trying to use `flasgger` for Swagger Docs:

```py
import pickle
from flask import Flask, request
from flasgger import Swagger
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('/media/arpon/allin1/Deploy Machine Learning & NLP Models with Dockers (DevOps)/Deploy Machine Learning & NLP Models with Dockers (DevOps)/iris/rf.pkl', 'rb') as model_file:
    model = pickle.load(model_file)

app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)

@app.route('/predict')
def predict_iris():
    """Example endpoint returning a prediction of iris
    ---
    parameters:
      - name: s_length
        in: query
        type: integer
        required: true
      - name: s_width
        in: query
        type: integer
        required: true
      - name: p_length
        in: query
        type: integer
        required: true
      - name: p_width
        in: query
        type: integer
        required: true

    """
    s_length = request.args.get("s_length")
    s_width = request.args.get("s_width")
    p_length = request.args.get("p_length")
    p_width = request.args.get("p_width")
    
    prediction = model.predict(np.array([[s_length, s_width, p_length, p_width]]))
    return str(prediction)

@app.route('/predict_file', methods=["POST"])
def predict_iris_file():
    """Example file endpoint returning a prediction of iris
    ---
    parameters:
      - name: input_file
        in: formData
        type: file
        required: true   
        
    """
    input_data = pd.read_csv(request.files.get("input_file"), header=None)
    prediction = model.predict(input_data)
    return str(list(prediction))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

i also add

```
responses:
200:
```

but after adding this i got Fetch error. swagger is not starting and without this responses app is running but not giving any output.

Comment: Can you give full logs/traceback ?

Comment: -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 03:08:16] "GET /flasgger_static/swagger-ui.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 03:08:16] "GET /flasgger_static/swagger-ui-bundle.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 03:08:17] "GET /flasgger_static/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 03:08:17] "GET /apispec_1.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 03:09:28] "GET /predict?s_length=4.1&s_width=5.2&p_length=4.2&p_width=8.3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: hmm, the logs write 200 status code, in theory this is a sign that everything is fine. Wait a while, I want to reproduce this. Though I won't be able to do that until you clarify which version of flask and flaskgger you are using

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.
This is mainly because you don't have proper indentation for response parameter.
Try following with proper indentation:

responses:

```
200:

    description: The output values
```

Hope this helps!